# Direct/Indirect Object Pronoun OS

Tags: gramática, pronombres, españa

I know that, when it comes to the present progressive form, the direct object pronoun can be put either before the first verb or attached to the present participle (with the added accent), such as:

*Yo los estoy comiendo.* OR *Yo estoy comiéndolos.*

But, when it comes to the pronoun **os**, is it possible to attach it to the present participle? Although it seems orthographically displeasing in the Spanish language, would it be *Yo estoy buscándoos*?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could say

> Niños, llevo **lamándoos** a comer por diez minutos!
>
> Estoy **rogándoos** encarecidamente que dejéis eso y vengáis a comer

There might be some fine print. In [this example](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF) from RAE

> suplicamos + os = suplicámoos, y no *suplicamosos*.

Comment: Ok, so the double O would be pronounced as two separate syllables?

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like "oos" (rogándoos) and not "os" (_rogándos_)

Comment: @K.O'Hara doubled vowels in Spanish are generally pronounced thus: If neither have stress (*creerás*) they may almost entirely merge into a single vowel /cre.rás/.  If one has the stress, the vowel will length about 50% (not quite to a full double length) and the first or second half will be louder —depending on which one is stressed.  So *cree* will be just /cre:/ but with a sharp decrease in volume midway through.  *creé* will do the opposite, it's still /cre:/ but has a sharp increase in volume midway through.

Comment: Is it unusual, Diego?